# Axios запрос из VUEX хранилища

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Вопрос собственно простой:
Является ли отправка данных на сервер из `VUEX` хранилища:
(что то наподобие такого)

```
setTrackingData (state, value) {
  state.to_the_final_destination = value.to_the_final_destination;
  const res = axios.get("https://seo-gmbh.eu/invest/input.php");
}
```

Здоровым явлением в среде `vue.js(nuxt.js)` разработки? ) 
Допустимы ли такие такие подходы и являются ли они приемлемыми?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во VueX - Actions как раз предназначены для отправки запросов на сервер, об этом в документации сразу и сказано. И не забывайте, что функция должна быть асинхронной:

```
async getInfo() {
const res = await this.$axios.get('/test')
}
```